# Return page to left on refresh

Tags: jquery, refresh, scroll

I have a horizontal scrolling website and I'd like to have the page reset to the far left (original position) when the page is refreshed. As of now I've tried using jQuery .scrollLeft but can only get it to work when the page initially loads. Is there a way to set it to work when the page is refreshed or another way to accomplish this?

Comment: A page refresh would trigger a page load. Define *refresh*.

Comment: I want the the page to return to the far left (starting position) when the refresh button/F5 is pressed. Right now I've got - $(document).load().scrollLeft(0); - which works when the page is loaded the first time. However, it doesn't send the page back to the far left position though if you are already viewing the page and then hit the refresh button/F5, instead the page refreshes and continues to show what you were already viewing. Hope that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Even if you dont  use any JS , on refresh the page will go to left only!!  Will it go to right or center  if you dont use JS?

Comment: It will go to the position that was being viewed before the refresh. For example, say I had scrolled to the right 300px, when I refresh the page currently the page position will remain scrolled 300px to the right. What I'm looking for is for the page position to be reset to 0px (the far left).

Comment: Just got it to work, here's what I'm using in case anyone else ever has this issue: $(document).ready(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
 scrollLeft : 0 },800);                                                             
 }); -                    Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If the page position is not reset to top left after a refresh (F5/cmd R), this must be some kind of browser memory.

You could create a home anchor in your top left like this:

```
<a name="home">&nbsp;</a>
```

This example uses a non-breaking space as content, but you could wrap it aroudn your existing content.

Then refer to your page as http://www.example.com/page.html#home and it should overwrite browser memory. Replace the url with your own, keep the #home.

Added later:

You could force moving to the anchor on page load like this:

```
$(function() {
  window.location.href = "#anchor";
});
```

​Code on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/awata3/edit

$(function) is short for $(document).ready(function)

Comment: I actually already have exactly this for navigation purposes. Is there a way to tell the browser that on refresh to send the page back to this anchor no matter where the page was?

Comment: Added instructions to my original answer, hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

Just so I'm clear on what you're asking. You are talking about once the page has loaded and the user has scrolled to the right, then you are wanting the page to return to the starting position when refreshed instead of remaining on what the user was just viewing?

Answer (score 0):

set following in the end of your body tag in html. this should re-position the page to left top when refreshed or reloaded.

```
window.onload = function() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0); // set x and y position to 0 and 0 respectively.
};
```